# HAProxy stats page showing inconsistent statuses

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm currently using HAProxy as a load balancer for two webservers, and managing it through the Statistics page. The last couple of times I've done deployments (putting one server into maintenance mode, updating it, setting it back to READY then doing the other) I've noticed that the status keeps changing whenever the page refreshes. For example:

1. Set the `node0` of my service to `MAINT` - row changes to brown, shows as down.
2. 10 seconds later I refresh the stats page, `node0` now shows green and up
3. Refresh stats page again, `node0` now shows as down for maintenance.
4. Start performing the update on `node0`, return to stats page. `node0` now shows as up.
5. Set state of `node0` to `MAINT`, shows as down.
6. Finish update, set state of `node0` to `READY`. Row shows `node0` as up.
7. Set state of `node1` to `MAINT`.
8. Get a notification from my uptime monitor saying that my site has gone down.
9. Refresh the stats page, both nodes are in `MAINT`.
10. Panic and set `node0` to `READY` again. Stats page refreshes and shows both nodes as `READY`.

...etc...

This is obviousl bad for my users and my blood pressure as I don't feel I can trust HAProxy to accurately and reliably report the state of my application. My questions are:

1. Is there another way to see the state of HAProxy, e.g. a CLI. From what I can see from the docs, `haproxy` is only for managing the HAProxy service itself.
2. Are any other HAProxy users seeing this behaviour? Have you found any workarounds?

I'm using HAProxy 1.5.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple PIDs of HAProxy running. Check that the PID reported on the stats page between refreshes stays consistent.

Beyond that, you can interact with HAProxy via the CLI using socat. See [documentation here](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#9.2) for information on how to do so.

Comment: Got it in one, there are two instances of it running! Not sure why we've got two instances running on one box but that's another question entirely... Thanks for the socket commands link too, I want to script more of our manual management processes so that'll be really handy.